# Не открывает localhost/phpmyadmin на Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: ubuntu, phpmyadmin, apache2

Не открывает phpmyadmin по адресу **localhost/phpmyadmin**

```
<?php
    /* vim: set expandtab sw=4 ts=4 sts=4: */
    /**
     * Main loader script
     *
     * @package PhpMyAdmin
     */
    /**
     * Gets some core libraries and displays a top message if required
     */
    require_once 'libraries/common.inc.php';

    /**
     * display Git revision if requested
     */
    require_once 'libraries/display_git_revision.lib.php';
    require_once 'libraries/Template.class.php';

    /**
     * pass variables to child pages
     */
    $drops = array(
        'lang',
        'server',
        'collation_connection',
        'db',
        'table'
    );
...
```

В Mozilla Firefox:

```
    addJSON( 'list', PMA_RecentFavoriteTable::getInstance('recent')->getHtmlList() ); exit; } if ($GLOBALS['PMA_Config']->isGitRevision()) { if (isset($_REQUEST['git_revision']) && $GLOBALS['is_ajax_request'] == true) { PMA_printGitRevision(); exit; } echo '
    '; } // Handles some variables that may have been sent by the calling script $GLOBALS['db'] = ''; $GLOBALS['table'] = ''; $show_query = '1'; // Any message to display? if (! empty($message)) { echo PMA_Util::getMessage($message); unset($message); } $common_url_query = PMA_URL_getCommon(); $mysql_cur_user_and_host = ''; // when $server > 0, a server has been chosen so we can display // all MySQL-related information if ($server > 0) { include 'libraries/server_common.inc.php'; include 'libraries/StorageEngine.class.php'; // Use the verbose name of the server instead of the hostname // if a value is set $server_info = ''; if (! empty($cfg['Server']['verbose'])) { $server_info .= htmlspecialchars($cfg['Server']['verbose']); if ($GLOBALS['cfg']['ShowServerInfo']) { $server_info .= ' ('; } } if ($GLOBALS['cfg']['ShowServerInfo'] || empty($cfg['Server']['verbose'])) { $server_info .= $GLOBALS['dbi']->getHostInfo(); } if (! empty($cfg['Server']['verbose']) && $GLOBALS['cfg']['ShowServerInfo']) { $server_info .= ')'; } $mysql_cur_user_and_host = $GLOBALS['dbi']->fetchValue('SELECT USER();'); // should we add the port info here? $short_server_info = (!empty($GLOBALS['cfg']['Server']['verbose']) ? $GLOBALS['cfg']['Server']['verbose'] : $GLOBALS['cfg']['Server']['host']); } echo '
    ' . "\n"; // Anchor for favorite tables synchronization. echo PMA_RecentFavoriteTable::getInstance('favorite')->getHtmlSyncFavoriteTables(); echo '
    '; if ($server > 0 || count($cfg['Servers']) > 1 ) { if ($cfg['DBG']['demo']) { echo '
    '; echo '
' . __('phpMyAdmin Demo Server') . '
'; echo '

'; printf( __( 'You are using the demo server. You can do anything here, but ' . 'please do not change root, debian-sys-maint and pma users. ' . 'More information is available at %s.' ), 'demo.phpmyadmin.net' ); echo '
'; echo '
'; } echo '
'; echo '
...
```

...

1. На чистую Ubuntu 16.04 LTS установил php `sudo apt-get install php`*
2. Далее mysql `sudo apt-get install php-mysql` `sudo apt-get install mysql-server`. Появилось окошко с настройками в терминале для MySQL:
   user:  "root"
   New password for the MySQL:  passw1
3. Устанавливаю phpmyadmin: `sudo apt-get install phpmyadmin php-mbstring php-gettext` (с апачем в зависимостях)
4. Настраивал phpmyadmin в терминале по [гайду](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/phpmyadmin-ubuntu-16-04-ru):
   1) выбираем apache2
   2) Configure database for phpmyadmin with dbconfig-common?  жмем "yes" 
   3) MySQL application password for phpmyadmin: "passw1"
5. Настроил даже [config.inc.php](http://www.aitishnik.ru/web/ampinst/ustanovka-phpmyadmin.html):

`$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'localhost';`
`$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysqli';`
`$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'tcp';`
`$cfg['Servers'][$i]['compress'] = false;`
`$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config';`
`$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';`
`$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = 'пароль';`
**Ну что же еще нужно настроить для того чтобы получить веб интерфейс phpmyadmin  по адресу localhost/phpmyadmin ?** Настроить Apach2 ? Как ?

UPD: Добавил логи apache2  /var/log/apache2/error.log  :

```
[Fri Jun 23 15:42:48.860043 2017] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 26503:tid 140078343305088] AH00489: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) configured -- resuming normal operations


[Fri Jun 23 15:42:48.860131 2017] [core:notice] [pid 26503:tid 140078343305088] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
```

Вот это все что было. Удалил все, зашел на адрес localhost/ потом на localhost/phpmyadmin/ и скопировал сюда логи. Какие логи, и где они находяться, нужно еще вставить?
**И да, если что, то апачь нужен только для того чтобы открывать phpmyadmin.**

Вот конфиги:

- /etc/apache2/conf-aviable/ файл [phpmyadmin.conf](https://codepen.io/discipleartem/pen/weqObp)(с пометкой как
  ссылка)
- /etc/apache2/ файл [apache2.conf](https://codepen.io/discipleartem/pen/EXvMBY)
- /etc/phpmyadmin файл [apache.conf](https://codepen.io/discipleartem/pen/BZdbgJ)
- /etc/phpmyadmin файл [config.inc.php](https://codepen.io/discipleartem/pen/zzdbVg)
- /etc/php/7.0/cli файл [php.ini](https://codepen.io/discipleartem/pen/PjKLMJ)
- /etc/php/7.0/[mods-available](https://codepen.io/discipleartem/pen/vZJMYx) (список расширений, т.е. ini файлов в папке)
  После очередных настроек по гайдам поломался php (не загружились расширения). Пришлось переустановить (обновил конфиги)

Comment: Не открывает почему? Какая-то ошибка? Что в логах?

Comment: @sanmai какой именно лог интересует и где его найти ?

Comment: Вот ссылка как установить их. Не раз пробовал этим методом на разных железах. Везде работало нормально.
https://losst.ru/ustanovka-lamp-ubuntu-16-04

Comment: Вопрос в том что и без конфига config.inc.php у тебя должен был подключатся PHPMyAdmin

Comment: @Самвел прийдеться всетаки  попробывать LAMP а я так не хотел. Хотел все самому по отдельности установить и настроить...

Comment: Вы уже установили LAMP ))) и все же для меня загадка почему у вас не работает PhpMyAdmin ведь и команды установки у вас `правильные`

Comment: посмотрите есть ли у вас в `/etc/apache2/conf-aviable/` файл `phpmyadmin.conf`

Comment: @ Самвел да есть - https://codepen.io/discipleartem/pen/rwzpNX

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60981/discussion-between--and-discipleartem).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

После настройки php.ini (/etc/php/7.0/cli) по [гайду](https://losst.ru/ustanovka-php-7-v-ubuntu) открылся phpmyadmin по адресу http://localhost/phpmyadmin/ . 
Вот мой конфиг [php.ini](https://codepen.io/discipleartem/pen/jwGyyL):

```
max_execution_time=600
memory_limit=128M
error_reporting=0
display_errors=0
log_errors=0
user_ini.filename=
realpath_cache_size=2M
cgi.check_shebang_line=0

zend_extension=opcache.so
opcache.enable_cli=1
opcache.save_comments=0
opcache.fast_shutdown=1
opcache.validate_timestamps=1
opcache.revalidate_freq=60
opcache.use_cwd=1
opcache.max_accelerated_files=100000
opcache.max_wasted_percentage=5
opcache.memory_consumption=128
opcache.consistency_checks=0
```

Answer (score 0):

Может быть довольно много причин. Первый вопрос - что показывает апач на странице? Код ответа какой?
Скорее всего просто не поставлен какой-то нужный модуль для PHP, но без текста ошибок из лога это гадание на кофейной гуще.

Comment: добавил логи. Apach2 показывает странную страницу с "It works!" и кучей настроек

Comment: Апач работает. Он показывает страницу по умолчанию, но не 404. А что покажет localhost/phpmyadmin/index.php ?

Comment: Показывает php код как в вопросе

Comment: т.е. интерпретатор PHP не работает. Следовательно у вас проблема с PHP.

Comment: @Самве Я создал файл .php и открыл его с помощью php -S localhost:3000 путь_к_файлу и все открыло, сработало.  Но я не настраивал php.ini если знаете гайды для настройки php.ini для Ubuntu - прошу поделиться

Comment: Прошу https://losst.ru/nastrojka-fajla-php-ini

Comment: там и про настройку расширений тоже говорится

Comment: @Самвел к сожалению там про настройку расширений как раз и нету, у меня в ini файле нет никаких расширений с ".so" которое нужно раскомментировать. А где расширения находяться, какие нужны и как их прописать в ini файл я не вкурсе

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60983/discussion-between-discipleartem-and-).