# Настройка php.ini Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: php, ubuntu, php.ini

После установки php командой `sudo apt-get install php` а также расширений типа `sudo apt-get install php-mysql` нужно ли прописывать их подключение в /etc/php/7.0/cli/php.ini ? 
А то после рекомендаций в очереднойм гайде раскомментировать строчку `;extension=msql.so` интерпритатор ломаеться.
 **Какие минимальные расширения нужны для веб разработки и как их правильно подключить (нужно ли прописывать их подключение в php.ini и как?) ?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В Ubuntu не нужно править основной `php.ini` для подключения модулей (справедливо как минимум для тех которые устанавливаются из репозитория самой ubuntu).

Конфиги подключающие модули кладутся в директорию `/etc/php/7.0/mods-available/` или аналогичную, версия (`7.0` в данном случае) может быть другой или отсутствовать вовсе, в зависимости от версии Ubuntu (последнее предполагаю основываясь на опыте использования старых версий Debian).

Для активации/дезактивации модуля нужно создать/удалить в директории `/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/` или `/etc/php/7.0/fpm/conf.d/` симлинк (символическую ссылку, см. `man ln`) соответствующий конфиг из директории `/etc/php/7.0/mods-available/`. Такие симлинки создаются по умолчанию после установки пакета с соответствующим модулем, так-что по умолчанию для активации модуля не нужно делать ничего.

Директория `/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/` содержит конфигурационные файлы (обычно это только подключения модулей) для PHP версии 7.0 работающего в режиме командной строки (cli).
Директория `/etc/php/7.0/fpm/conf.d/` содержит то-же самое для PHP 7.0 работающего в режиме FastCGI-сервера (демон php-fpm).

P.S. Для вебразработки минимально нужное желание и понимание того с чем ты работаешь, а не модули. Модули — вторичны

Comment: К сожалению мне пришлост поправить конфиги php чтобы заработал phpMyAdmin с apach2 (https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/682518/%D0%9D%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-localhost-phpmyadmin-%D0%BD%D0%B0-ubuntu-16-04-lts)